# SPA - simple sign up form

Tags: reactjs, oop, authentication, frontend

not sure if anyone can help me with this.. gotta make a SinglePageApplication, a simple sign up form, the screens required are:
step 1 - asking for users name and phone number
step 2 - asking for users email and data of births
step 3 - should present all the users details for confirmation
step 4 - sign up completion screen

not sure how to solve the transition from 1st to 2nd step. also, if I have to use session or local storage to present users details on step 3..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use some SPA framework like Angular or Vue.js. If you want to use vanilla js you should check DOM manipulation. Just change the content of your site for each stage. Or simply add display: none. There are hundreds of solutions. If you do not make redirection your data can be kept in variables i don't think that using local/session storage is necessary. Unless you want to keep your data after refreshing form.

Comment: Fair enough. no redirection, no back end validation is required, should be set up so that it would be simple to implement it after each step. 
I gotta use react for it, has to be done in a frontEnd framework. I think this can be done by using Formik and Yup libraries for validation..